# installing libxcb - No package 'xproto' found

Tags: linux, xcb

I am trying to install libxcb:
I started with xcb-proto 1.11 with:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

Which works without errors.

But when i try to install libXau-1.0.8 with:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

I get the error:

```
checking for XAU... configure: error: Package requirements (xproto) were not met:

No package 'xproto' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable,...
```

I am not sure if i missed some important parameter for the installation or something ?

Comment: I think you want to `apt-get install x11proto-core-dev`. If that doesn't help, please tell us which distro you have. If it does help, please don't forget to give feedback.

Comment: `xcb-proto` and `xproto` are 2 different packages in x11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank your for your help!

I was missing these two libs: `libpthread-stubs` and `xproto`